# Parse.com & small business app : best practice to use product keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse SDK in an app for a small business with approximately 3000 customers. I am using the built-in class PFUser to sign up all users upon first launch, but I also need to :

- limit the (total) number of users/clients for the app
- give a privilege to the business staff, to allow them to send remote notifications (from their own devices) to all the store clients

To do so, I was thinking about this process :

1. I generate a list of "userKey". Each userKey is a string made of 15 characters, with digits, lowercase and uppercase. I plan to generate these keys from a (free) website.
2. I upload these userKeys in Parse database. Each userKey would be stored as an instance of a UserKey class. I would manually add the column/attribute "isAdmin" (Boolean) set to TRUE to a given number of userKeys (say 8-10). All other keys would have these attribute set to FALSE.
3. I give this set of userKeys to the business owner. She then has a given number of "client" userKeys, say 990, and 10 more "admin" userKeys.
4. Whoever the user may be, she is prompted to sign in when the app is launched on the device for the first time (in fact, I was thinking about checking if a [PFUser currentUser] was already cached on disk? If not, show the logIn/signIn page.)
5. This new user enters her mail address as her username, her password, and the userKey she has been given by the business owner.
6. It the mail, password and userKey input format is correct (checked with a regex), I query the UserKey (stored on Parse DB) that has the same ID entered by the user
7. If this UserKey does not even exist, I display an alert
8. It this UserKey exists, I look into its "user" property, that is userKey[@"user"] with the KVC notation
9. If this field is set, then it means that the input userKey is already linked to a PFUser (that is, it has already been given to a client of the store). I display and alert.
10. If userKey[@"user"] is not set, then the userKey is "free". The last step is to know wether this new user is a staff member of the store, or just a client.
11. I look into userKey[@"admin"] where admin is a Boolean value entered manually. If userKey[@"admin"] = TRUE, then I authorize this PFUser (now cached on disk) to send remote notifications.

The code would look like this :

```
- (void)signUpNewUser {

NSString *userMail = self.mailTextField.text;
NSString *userPassword = self.passwordTextField.text;
NSString *userKeyInput = self.userKeyTextField.text;

// == 1. Check Mail ==
if (![self validateEmail:userMail]) {
    [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Mail invalide" subTitle:@"Entrez une adresse mail valide."];
    return;
}
// == 2. Check Password ==
if ([self validatePassword:userPassword]) {

    // == 3. Check UserKey Input Format ==
    if ([self validateUserKeyFormat:userKeyInput]) {

        // == 4. Check if this UserKey exists ==
        PFQuery *userKeyQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserKey"];
        [userKeyQuery whereKey:@"userKeyString" equalTo:userKeyInput];

        PFObject *fetchedUserKey = [userKeyQuery getFirstObject];

        // == 4.1. UserKey does not exist ==
        if (!fetchedUserKey) {
            [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Clé inconnue" subTitle:@"La clé saisie n'existe pas. Demandez au responsable du Club une clé personnelle différente."];
            return;
        }

        // == 4.2. UserKey exists, check if it is available ==
        if (fetchedUserKey) {

            // == 5.1. UserKey is already taken ==
            if (fetchedUserKey[@"user"] != nil) {
                [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Clé déjà utilisée" subTitle:@"La clé saisie est déjà utilisée par un autre membre du Club. Demandez au responsable du Club une clé personnelle différente."];
                return;
            }

            // == 5.2. UserKey is free. Create new PFUser, link with userKey & signUp ==
            if (fetchedUserKey[@"user"] == nil) {

                PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
                newUser.username = userMail;
                newUser.password = userPassword;
                newUser[@"isAdmin"] = fetchedUserKey[@"isAdmin"];

                [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"\n\n ** signUp ErrorDesc: %@\nError Code= %i",error.localizedDescription,error.code);
                    }
                    if (!error) {
                        NSLog(@"\n\n ** signUp SUCCESS!");

                        // I assume Parse will automatically create a One-to-One relationship between the UserKey and the PFUser. Am I right ?
                        fetchedUserKey[@"user"] = newUser;
                        [fetchedUserKey save];

                        newUser[@"userKey"] = fetchedUserKey;
                        [newUser save];

                        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have tested the code, it works fine and handles the various cases (iPhone lost, wrong input format, userKey already taken, etc.).

But since it is the first time I have to limit user access upon authentification, I had like to know if this way of doing things is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com